# str.endswith() does not seem to consider the first if statment

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.3, ends-with

I am using Python 3.3.2 on a windows 7 32bit machine.

I am trying the following syntax:

```
def make_from(inputString):
    if inputString.endswith('y'):
        fixed = inputString[:-1] + 'ies'
    if inputString.endswith(('o', 'ch', 's', 'sh', 'x', 'z')):
        fixed = inputString[:] + 'es'
    else: 
        fixed = inputString + 's'
    return fixed
```

The first IF condition does not seem to be taking effect .. the others work for example if I type `make_from('happy')` it returns `'happys'`, but if it type `make_from('brush')` it returns `'brushes'`.

I guess I am missing something.. any idea whats going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter `happy` the following two statements execute:

```
if inputString.endswith('y'):
    fixed = inputString[:-1] + 'ies'
```

and

```
else: 
    fixed = inputString + 's'
```

because the second `if` statement is `False` for `happy`. So `fixed` is first assigned `happies` but ends up as `happys` because the first assignment is *replaced*.

Use `elif` instead of `if` for the second test:

```
def make_from(inputString):
    if inputString.endswith('y'):
        fixed = inputString[:-1] + 'ies'
    elif inputString.endswith(('o', 'ch', 's', 'sh', 'x', 'z')):
        fixed = inputString[:] + 'es'
    else: 
        fixed = inputString + 's'
    return fixed
```

or use multiple return statements:

```
def make_from(inputString):
    if inputString.endswith('y'):
        return inputString[:-1] + 'ies'
    if inputString.endswith(('o', 'ch', 's', 'sh', 'x', 'z')):
        return inputString[:] + 'es'
    return inputString + 's'
```